# inkscape very slow: 5-15sec to insert or select a line with a marker

Tags: inkscape

in inkscape (0.92 and 1.0) if a file has many objects:

```
 1. "copy & insert" / select lines                               < 1sec
 2. "copy & insert" / select lines with enpdoint (e.g. arrow)   3-15sec
```

It does not matter if inserting 1 new item or 20 at a time ... both take up to 15sec (I mention this just for clarity of the effect - cloning is not the point here).

It is the same behavior on a laptop i5 as on a high performance desktop i7 under windows.

Any idea how to speed up working or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really experienced that much of a delay when copy and pasting paths with markers, even when the are hundreds of them. It seems excessive. But yes, Inkscape can get laggy if you have an excessive number of nodes, effects, etc. I use a Windows 10 PC, with an i5 processor.

Instead of just copy and pasting objects repeatedly, which isn't very efficient anyway, try creating a clone of an object, and copy and paste clones. That will help speed up Inkscape, and help keep the SVG file size smaller.

Also if you start noticing too much lag, then try doing *Edit > Clean Up document*. That usually helps. Do it frequently if necessary.

There are many more tips and methods to avoid performance issues here: https://inkscape.org/learn/tutorials/avoid-performance-issues/

Comment: thanks for your hints - I updated the question to be more clear. The topics about avoiding performance issues are known to me, but do not change anything. Cloning is not an option as it is about different elements - in total the effect starts from around 40. At 200  I have a delay of around 3sec already. By the way: the same applies to selecting the objects. Selecting a bunch of lines takes 0.x sec whereas selecting a bunch of lines with markers takes >5sec. There must be an operation in the data structure that delays the whole thing.